# How to restrict specail character Grave accent (backtick) in text box using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms, angular-validation

i wants to validate text box which allows special character like []^_,atoz,1 to 10 characters.am using ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" it allows to enter but it doesnot enable submit button.But the problem is we should not allow user to enter special characters especially  Grave accent (`):

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/">
```

and also am using following validation:

```
<input type="text" restrict="^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$/">
```

kindly help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Directive

```
directive('noSpecialChar', function() {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

                            if (inputValue == null)
                                return ''
                            var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
                            if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                                modelCtrl.$render();
                            }
                            return cleanInputValue;

                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' no-Special-Char />
```

Comment: hey  tried this one it allows white space.i needs to allow user to enter alphanumeric,special characters like []_^.not white space

Comment: You can remove all the char which you want to allow from this line var cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');